# How to Merge Two Differnt Images in Third Image?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to Merge Two Differnt images in one Image,
First of All I generated BARCODE Image Using BarcodeLib.DLL,
and then Generated SKULabelImage using Bitmap Class,now i want to Set
"SKULabelImage to Bottom Of BARCODE Image" but When i try to Merge this Two Images in 
outputImage,  it only prints BarcodeImage,  i dont know where is wrong, please check my code
give me suggestions.I m created this Application In "Windows Form"

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string Date = textBox1.Text;
        string Number = textBox2.Text;
        if (Number != "")
        {

            int NoofLables = Convert.ToInt32(Number);

            for (int i = 1; i <= NoofLables; i++)
            {

                string Filename = "Barcodeimage" + i + ".jpg";

                string imgsavepath = "E:\\Pankaj\\BarcodeDemo\\BarcodeDemo\\BarcodeImage\\" + Filename;

               // string imgSkupath = "E:\\Pankaj\\BarcodeDemo\\BarcodeDemo\\BarcodeImage\\" + "FinalImg.jpg";
                BarcodeLib.SaveTypes savetype = BarcodeLib.SaveTypes.UNSPECIFIED;
                savetype = BarcodeLib.SaveTypes.JPG;
                System.IO.FileStream MemStream = new FileStream(imgsavepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                System.Drawing.Image barcodeImage = null;
                Bitmap FinalImage = null;
                BarcodeLib.Barcode b = new BarcodeLib.Barcode();


                //b.IncludeLabel = true;
                b.LabelFont = new Font("Arial", 5);

                string sku = "SKU:VXN4214IN";
                string StringToEncode = "16280/" + i+' '+ sku;


                //BARCODE IMAGE
                barcodeImage = b.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128, "001234", Color.Black, Color.White, 113, 18);


                 //SKULableImage
                Bitmap SkuImage = new Bitmap(113, 18, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

                RectangleF rectf = new RectangleF(10, 10, 113, 18);
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(SkuImage);

                graphics.DrawString(StringToEncode, new Font("Arial", 7), Brushes.Black, rectf);



                //Method For Meging Images
                // I Took outputImage Image in "FinalImage"
                FinalImage = MergeTwoImages(barcodeImage, SkuImage);




                 b.SaveImage(MemStream, savetype);

                MemStream.Close();
                FinalImage.Dispose();
            }

            label3.Text = "Images Generated..!";
            label3.Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            label3.Visible = true;
            label3.Text = "Please Enter No. Of Labels";
        }
    }




public static Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
    {
        if (firstImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage");
        }

        if (secondImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage");
        }

        //int outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width ? firstImage.Width : secondImage.Width;

        //int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height + 1;

        int outputImageWidth = 226;

        int outputImageHeight = 50;


        //Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight);

        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
        {


            graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Point(0, 0));
            graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(0, 0));

            //graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), firstImage.Size),
            //   new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), firstImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
            //graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Rectangle(new Point(0, firstImage.Height + 1), secondImage.Size),
            //    new Rectangle(new Point(), secondImage.Size), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            graphics.Dispose();
        }

        return outputImage;
    }
```

Comment: I think you probably have to change the location of where you are drawing the second image. It it probably overlaying the first image. Try something like graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(50, 50)); just for a test

Comment: I  tried This  "graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(50, 50));"
but Nothing Happen.

Comment: First Of All i want to see both images in output image..then i can mange Cordinates..

Comment: Try to save SkuImage to a file Bitmap.Save to ensure it is actually what you think it should be.

Comment: when I try to save only SKu Image it Saved to Speficic folder path,Using This I Saved sku image.. SkuImage.Save(imgSkupath); 
but when i try to save both images that time somthing went wrong

Comment: graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(50, 50)) won't work on its own if the output image height is only 50. Try also changing int outputImageHeight = 100.

Comment: Are you sure you're not writing the white pixels too, effectively overwrite the entire image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue try with this code. the second image position need to be calculate it.

```
    public Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
    {
        if (firstImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage");
        }

        if (secondImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage");
        }

        int outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width ? firstImage.Width : secondImage.Width;
        int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height + 1;
        Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
        {
            graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Point(0, 0));
            graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(0, firstImage.Height + 1));
        }

        return outputImage;
    }
```

sample code which i was tried. its worked as expected.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Bitmap one = new Bitmap(113, 18);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(one))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 0, 0, 113, 18);
            g.DrawString("ONE", new Font("Arial", 7), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 113, 18), new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center });
        }
        Bitmap two = new Bitmap(113, 18, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(two))
        {
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Yellow, 0, 0, 113, 18);
            g.DrawString("TWO", new Font("Arial", 7), Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(0, 0, 113, 18), new StringFormat { Alignment = StringAlignment.Center, LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center });
        }

        BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
        BackgroundImage = MergeTwoImages(one, two);
    }

    public Bitmap MergeTwoImages(Image firstImage, Bitmap secondImage)
    {
        if (firstImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("firstImage");
        }

        if (secondImage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("secondImage");
        }

        int outputImageWidth = firstImage.Width > secondImage.Width ? firstImage.Width : secondImage.Width;
        int outputImageHeight = firstImage.Height + secondImage.Height + 1;
        Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(outputImageWidth, outputImageHeight);
        using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
        {
            graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            graphics.DrawImage(firstImage, new Point(0, 0));
            graphics.DrawImage(secondImage, new Point(0, firstImage.Height + 1));
        }

        return outputImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: It Only Prints Barcode Image..Even I changed Color Of SkuImage because i can see it..but nothing happen..but THAnks for Help.

Comment: i have edited my post with full working sample. provide the output image which you are getting. which may help to find the issue.